# Drag and Drop batch based on a java file with input and output

Tags: batch-file

I tried to convert a .lc file to a .lua file, using a java app "unluac", and I did this code:

```
@echo on
type %1
for /r %%o in (cd %1, %CD%) do (
    set o = %%~ni
)
echo %1
echo "%~dp0unluac_2021_08_29b.jar"
echo %output%
set preoutput = %1
set out = %preoutput:~-3%
java -jar "%~dp0unluac_2021_08_29b.jar" "%1" > "%1%.lua"
pause
```

I let the ECHO on ON to get the logs and know what work and what doesn't work.
The file is converted, but or it take "input.lc.lua" or it just out ".lua".
I tried to substring the characters in the filename (the .lc) but it didn't work and returned an empty string.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but you are setting variables which you never seem to use, nevertheless never put spaces after variable name and value as that will create a variable name with a trailing space and a value with a leading space. example: `set "var=val"`. Then, your for loop uses metavariable `%%o` but you `set o` as an expansion of `%%i`?? then suddenly you go from `%1` to `%1%` which is a variable that does not exist. Lastly, define full path to `java` and as well as full path to output. I suggest you edit the question and add only the relevant parts, please.

Comment: I don't know very well this language, I tried to substring the file extension of the filename because I don't know how I can modify that from a variable path

Comment: a pretty good start would be to run from `cmd` the commands `for /?` and `set /?`.

Comment: Okay, then how do I susbtring the variable %1 ? I cannot do "%1:~-3%, it just won't work, it will ?

Comment: Have you tried `"%~n1.lua"` or `%~dpn1.lua` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear and your code makes no sense.

You must do yourself a favor and open `cmd` then run `set /?` and `for /?` to see all the help you need.

Anyway, you seemingly just need to strip the extension. there is an expansion model you can use i.e `%~dpnx1` Those are `d`rive, `p`ath. `n`ame and e`x`tension. Therefore you should be able to run something similar to:

```
start "" "C:\<Path to Java>\java.exe" -jar "%~dp0unluac_2021_08_29b.jar" "%~1" > "%~n1.lua"
```

Comment: It is not arrogance at all, you cannot express emotion in text unless you use emoticons. It is how you interpret it. Glad it helped though.